# MongoDB update: I can't update my documents in MongoDB with flask API

Tags: python, json, mongodb, flask

I want to update the month of document in mongoDB. for example changing the `"month": "June"` to `"month": "May"` in the document that has `"truck_id": "A01"`

This are my documents in MongoDB:

```
{
"0": {
    "available": "no",
    "end_date": "10",
    "month": "June",
    "start_date": "15",
    "truck_id": "A01"
},
"1": {
    "available": "yes",
    "end_date": null,
    "month": "June",
    "start_date": null,
    "truck_id": "A02"
}
```

}

And this is the code in my API:

```
@app.route('/update', methods=["PUT"])
    def updateElement():
        object_id = request.get_json()
        object_update = request.get_json()
        query = SampleTable.update_one(object_id, object_update)
        return jsonify(query)
```

When I tried to test my API with postman I write this in postmans raw body tester :

```
{
   "0":{  
      "truck_id":"A01"
   },
      "$set":{
         "month":"May"
      }
}
```

But when I tried this get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\umut8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\umut8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\umut8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\umut8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\umut8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\umut8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "D:\Dev\api_test\appi\app.py", line 29, in updateElement
    query = SampleTable.update_one(object_id, object_update)
  File "C:\Users\umut8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1023, in update_one
    common.validate_ok_for_update(update)
  File "C:\Users\umut8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\common.py", line 567, in validate_ok_for_update
    raise ValueError('update only works with $ operators')
ValueError: update only works with $ operators
```

I know probably many things I do in here is wrong and I probably ask my question in a bad way but I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `replace_one()` instead of `update_one()`. The 3rd parameter of `replace_one()` is `upsert`.

```
SampleTable.replace_one(object_id, object_update, True)
```

The exception was raised because you didn't specify any [update operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/) e.g. `$set`.

Comment: But how can I test it in postman. I am not so familiar with the JSON so I don't know how I can get one JSON object to ---object_id = request.get_json()---  and another to  ----object_update = request.get_json() -----